# Launchpad occasionally stalls for few minutes

Tags: macos, launchpad

This is happening occasionally and I can't nail the source. What happens is that sometimes after my Mac wakes up from a sleep, I can not launch any apps using Launchpad. I can click the launchpad icon, and I can see the launchpad, but whatever app I click there - it won't run. Only after few minutes all the apps that I've clicked start all at once and then launchpad starts to work fine.

During this stall I can run apps that are in my dock without a problem - they start immediately. I can use terminal and work normally within open apps. The only problem is that for few minutes I can't launch new apps from launchpad.

What's interesting, during this stall, when I click on app icons in the launchpad, the launchpad does not close. I can see it all the time. I need to click on a blank space around icons to close the launchpad.

Any tips on this? I tried looking at the syslog, but frankly, I have no idea what to look for. `system.log` is a bit littered with stuff that I'm not familiar with. I don't even know what to look for.

### [Update]

It happened again today. I wanted to launch `Notes` app and the launchpad stalled again. I've tried searching logs and this is what I've found:

This entry is really annoying - it is littering the whole log, so I've removed it from results:
`sharingd[322]: Stopping Handoff advertising`

This is the log from the moment I noticed that launchpad is stalled. You can see that I've immediately launched console to tail the `system.log`. I can't tell the exact time. Everything lasted for 2-3 minutes:

```
09.12.2014 10:57:59,668 discoveryd[48]: Basic Sockets SetDelegatePID() failed for PID[7681] errno[3] result[-1]
09.12.2014 10:58:14,029 discoveryd[48]: Basic Sockets SetDelegatePID() failed for PID[7681] errno[3] result[-1]
09.12.2014 10:58:32,552 discoveryd[48]: Basic Sockets SetDelegatePID() failed for PID[7681] errno[3] result[-1]
09.12.2014 10:59:02,015 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.quicklook[25085]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
09.12.2014 10:59:05,353 discoveryd[48]: Basic Sockets SetDelegatePID() failed for PID[7681] errno[3] result[-1]
09.12.2014 10:59:18,018 discoveryd[48]: Basic Sockets SetDelegatePID() failed for PID[484] errno[3] result[-1]
09.12.2014 10:59:21,325 login[25086]: USER_PROCESS: 25086 ttys001
09.12.2014 10:59:38,000 kernel[0]: smb2_smb_parse_change_notify: smb_rq_reply failed 60
09.12.2014 10:59:42,102 discoveryd[48]: Basic Sockets SetDelegatePID() failed for PID[7681] errno[3] result[-1]
09.12.2014 10:59:43,000 kernel[0]: smb_fid_get_kernel_fid: No SMB 2/3 fid found for fid 22de630e7003b4f9
09.12.2014 10:59:43,000 kernel[0]: smb_iod_reconnect: Reconnected share FRANCESCA with server Mac mini (Anna)._smb._tcp.local
09.12.2014 10:59:43,840 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
09.12.2014 10:59:44,562 Notes[25097]: *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
09.12.2014 10:59:44,769 sandboxd[360]: ([291]) softwareupdated(291) deny mach-lookup com.apple.webinspector
09.12.2014 10:59:44,784 sandboxd[360]: ([453]) storedownloadd(453) deny mach-lookup com.apple.webinspector
09.12.2014 10:59:46,443 mds[32]: ERROR: where = <RPCChannelRequest()> why = <MDSChannelRequestRPC()> error code = 0x16c9a036 reason = <rpc_s_connection_closed (dce / rpc)>
09.12.2014 10:59:46,443 mds[32]: ERROR: _MDSChannelRPCRequest: RPCChannelRequest failed 5
09.12.2014 10:59:46,443 mds[32]: (Message.Error:142) MDSChannel RPC failure (fetchAllAttributes:forOIDArray:context:)
09.12.2014 10:59:46,443 mds[32]: (Store.Error:273) <MDSDistantStore 0x7ff9040785a0 shutdown:NO got shutdown notification:NO>{channel:0x7ff8fa5ec7c0 localPath:'/Volumes/Francesca'} MDSChannel failed -- initiating recovery
09.12.2014 10:59:56,654 mds[32]: (Server.Error:221) Failed to register path "/Volumes/Francesca" to store <MDSStoreToken: 0x7ff8fa764c50>{storeID:0x6b000060 registered:YES private:NO age:8h42m56s uuid:2C23554A-0D78-4575-9E41-09635551B697}
09.12.2014 10:59:56,854 Notes[25097]: *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
09.12.2014 10:59:56,871 Notes[25097]: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c68d64c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff87e126de objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c531068 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 360
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c5976b4 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 52
    4   Notes                               0x0000000103167d94 Notes + 101780
    5   Notes                               0x0000000103167c17 Notes + 101399
    6   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff92485cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8d8b9497 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 410
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8d8b92c0 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8da8dc5f __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 131
    10  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff92485cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d901ddc -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 144
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d933cb5 -[NSSegmentedCell _sendActionFrom:] + 49
    13  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff92485cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d91c916 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2731
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d9336a7 -[NSSegmentedCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 1160
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d91b139 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 714
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8de14f4f -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:] + 12827
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d89f50c -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 368
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d851096 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2238
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d6dde98 -[NSApplication run] + 711
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d6c92d4 NSApplicationMain + 1832
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff905565c9 start + 1
    23  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
09.12.2014 10:59:59,933 discoveryd[48]: Basic Sockets SetDelegatePID() failed for PID[484] errno[3] result[-1]
09.12.2014 11:00:45,348 discoveryd[48]: Basic Sockets SetDelegatePID() failed for PID[484] errno[3] result[-1]
09.12.2014 11:01:49,888 discoveryd[48]: Basic Sockets SetDelegatePID() failed for PID[7681] errno[3] result[-1]
09.12.2014 11:01:52,660 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
09.12.2014 11:01:52,879 sandboxd[360]: ([291]) softwareupdated(291) deny mach-lookup com.apple.webinspector
09.12.2014 11:01:52,899 sandboxd[360]: ([453]) storedownloadd(453) deny mach-lookup com.apple.webinspector
09.12.2014 11:01:52,927 Notes[25113]: *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
09.12.2014 11:01:55,704 Notes[25113]: *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
09.12.2014 11:01:55,706 Notes[25113]: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c68d64c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff87e126de objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c531068 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 360
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c5976b4 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 52
    4   Notes                               0x000000010915ed94 Notes + 101780
    5   Notes                               0x000000010915ec17 Notes + 101399
    6   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff92485cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8d8b9497 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 410
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8d8b92c0 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8da8dc5f __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 131
    10  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff92485cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d901ddc -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 144
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d933cb5 -[NSSegmentedCell _sendActionFrom:] + 49
    13  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff92485cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d91c916 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2731
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d9336a7 -[NSSegmentedCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 1160
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d91b139 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 714
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8de14f4f -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:] + 12827
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d89f50c -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 368
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d851096 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2238
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d6dde98 -[NSApplication run] + 711
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d6c92d4 NSApplicationMain + 1832
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff905565c9 start + 1
    23  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
09.12.2014 11:01:56,800 Notes[25113]: *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
09.12.2014 11:01:56,801 Notes[25113]: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c68d64c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff87e126de objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c531068 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 360
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8c5976b4 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 52
    4   Notes                               0x000000010915ed94 Notes + 101780
    5   Notes                               0x000000010915ec17 Notes + 101399
    6   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff92485cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8d8b9497 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 410
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8d8b92c0 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8da8dc5f __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 131
    10  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff92485cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d901ddc -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 144
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d933cb5 -[NSSegmentedCell _sendActionFrom:] + 49
    13  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff92485cd7 _os_activity_initiate + 75
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d91c916 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2731
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d9336a7 -[NSSegmentedCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 1160
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d91b139 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 714
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8de14f4f -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:] + 12827
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d89f50c -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 368
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d851096 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2238
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d6dde98 -[NSApplication run] + 711
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8d6c92d4 NSApplicationMain + 1832
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff905565c9 start + 1
    23  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
09.12.2014 11:01:58,684 Notes[25113]: *** WebKit discarding exception: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
09.12.2014 11:01:58,719 Notes[25113]: *** WebKit discarding exception: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
09.12.2014 11:01:58,775 Notes[25113]: *** WebKit discarding exception: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
09.12.2014 11:01:59,215 Notes[25113]: *** WebKit discarding exception: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
09.12.2014 11:01:59,223 Notes[25113]: *** WebKit discarding exception: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
09.12.2014 11:01:59,279 Notes[25113]: *** WebKit discarding exception: <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
```

### [Update 2]

Happened again today. I've looked at logs again and it looks like it's caused by Finder which tries to connect to some remote machine that is no longer available.

```
Dec 14 11:35:11 pc36.home discoveryd[48]: Basic Sockets SetDelegatePID() failed for PID[484] errno[3] result[-1]
Dec 14 11:35:32 pc36 kernel[0]: smbfs_lookup: Server failed Query Info 57
Dec 14 11:35:32 pc36.home KernelEventAgent[67]: tid 54485244 received event(s) VQ_DEAD (32)
Dec 14 11:35:32 pc36.home KernelEventAgent[67]: tid 54485244 type 'smbfs', mounted on '/Volumes/Francesca', from '//francesca@Mac%20mini%20%28Anna%29._smb._tcp.local/Francesca', dead
Dec 14 11:35:32 pc36.home KernelEventAgent[67]: tid 54485244 force unmount //francesca@Mac%20mini%20%28Anna%29._smb._tcp.local/Francesca from /Volumes/Francesca
Dec 14 11:35:32 pc36.home Finder[312]: No _kCFURLVolumeRefNumKey property for URL file:///Volumes/Francesca/
Dec 14 11:35:32 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec 14 11:35:32 pc36.home KernelEventAgent[67]: tid 54485244 found 1 filesystem(s) with problem(s)
Dec 14 11:35:32 pc36.home Finder[312]: No _kCFURLVolumeRefNumKey property for URL file:///Volumes/Recovery%20HD/
Dec 14 11:35:32 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec 14 11:35:32 pc36.home Finder[312]: CreateWithFileInfo failed to create URL with FSRef, falling back to blank icon.
Dec 14 11:35:32 pc36.home sharingd[322]: getVolumeRefNumForURL::CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey(NSCocoaErrorDomain, 256, "Nie można otworzyć pliku „Francesca”.")
Dec 14 11:35:32 pc36.home sharingd[322]: 11:35:32.184 : SDConnectedBrowser::getResourceValue Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Plik „Francesca” nie istnieje." UserInfo=0x7f9260d7cf70 {NSURL=file:///Volumes/Francesca/, NSFilePath=/Volumes/Francesca}
```

I'm not sure if that's coincidence, but after last message all the apps that I've clicked in the launchpad have started immediately. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: In `system.log` have a look at the timestamp. Entries relating to your Launchpad issue most likely have a timestamp very close to the point of time when you clicked on the Launchpad icon.

Comment: @patrix This happened again today. I've pasted log entries from that time.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you reset launchpad as this appears to be a bug/glitch of some sort.

Go to the Finder.
Hold down the Option key and click on the the Go menu.
Select Library.
Look for the Application Support folder. Open it.
Look for the Dock folder. Open it.
Locate files ending in ".db". Drag them into the Trash.
Go to the  menu and select Restart...
Click on the Restart button.
(Alternately, you can simply log out and log back in, if you prefer.)